# Running an ECS task from .net desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am writing a simple desktop application using C# on Visual Studio. I am using the AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.ECS nuget packages. The access credentials are provided through ADFS CLI method. Since there is not much documentation regarding the .net SDK for ECS, I need some help regarding the **Network Configuration** parameters required to start a Fargate task using an existing task definition and cluster.

I have tried the example code provided in the AWS .net SDK documentation.

```
var response = client.RunTask(new RunTaskRequest 
{
    Cluster = "default",
    TaskDefinition = "sleep360:1"
});

List<Task> tasks = response.Tasks;
```

I would like to start a Fargate task from this desktop application with the Subnets and Security Groups defined within the AWSVPCConfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should look something like this:

```
var response = client.RunTask(new RunTaskRequest 
{
    Cluster = "default",
    TaskDefinition = "sleep360:1"
    PlatformVersion = "LATEST",
    LaunchType = "FARGATE",
    NetworkConfiguration = new NetworkConfiguration
    {
        AwsvpcConfiguration = new AwsVpcConfiguration
        {
            Subnets = new List<string>() { "subnet-XXXXXXXX" },
            SecurityGroups = new List<string>() { "sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" },
            AssignPublicIp = AssignPublicIp.ENABLED
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue! Could you please give me a link to the source if you have found any documentation on this?

Comment: Only docs I've seen are the AWS SDK model docs: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ECS/TRunTaskRequest.html